# Unable to decode danish characters for email

Tags: c#, email

I have some code to send an email. data for email is coming from third party API, which will look like this `&#229;` equivalent of it is danish character `å`. but email shows s `&#229;` .
Is there any way i can transform this one in to correct?

My code to send mail is like this

```
  SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
            foreach (string toEmail in toEmails.Split(",".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                mail.To.Add(toEmail.Trim());
            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            mail.Body = body;
            mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = isHtml;
            mail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

            if (attachments != null)
            {
                foreach (string key in attachments.Keys)
                {
                    Attachment mailAttachment = new Attachment(attachments[key], key);
                    mail.Attachments.Add(mailAttachment);
                }
            }
            client.Send(mail);
            retValue = true;
```

Note: Fixed the issue by using L.B's answer . but i am still having some issues like
[image]
this. in my email body

Comment: Which utility class you use (HttpUtility/WebUtility)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [HttpUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [WebUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class

```
var str = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&#229;");

var str = WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&#229;");
```

Comment: Your code works correctly it solved the main issue. but I am still having some troubles. please look in to updated question

Comment: @Athul a) Probably you have an encoding problem but I can't say anything by just looking at this image b) After getting the answer, extending the question with new requirments is not a good behaviour.

Comment: I am really thank full for what you have done. But As you can see my problem never solved by your answer it just caused another issue (although i know your answer is absolutely correct for my question). So please don't talk like i have extended the question to put you in a bad situation.